# React-native build.grade page error - unexpected end of page

Tags: android, react-native, publish

I am trying to publish my first android app, and I am getting the following error when trying to use the command

$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

The error is

> startup failed:
>     build file '/Users/adamkatz/Projects/Brandfoundry/react-native/sassi_old/android/app/build.gradle': 126: unexpected char: 0xFFFF @ line 126, column 2.

line 126 is the final line of the project, column one has a } and column 2 is empty,

Any ideas?  Thanks so much

Here is the build.gradle file

https://gist.github.com/AdamLava/08bd80a49413e23cd2661d214c736c59

And the full command line is

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/adamkatz/Projects/Brandfoundry/react-native/sassi_old/android/app/build.gradle' line: 125
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file '/Users/adamkatz/Projects/Brandfoundry/react-native/sassi_old/android/app/build.gradle'.

  > startup failed:
  >   build file '/Users/adamkatz/Projects/Brandfoundry/react-native/sassi_old/android/app/build.gradle': 125: unexpected char: 0xFFFF @ line 125, column 2.
  >    }
  >     ^

  1 error
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.976 secs

Comment: Can you please post the entire log  as well as build.gradle file for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the time, added

Comment: You have added 'compile project(':react-native-fs')' twice in your build.gradle. Try removing one and do release build. Let me know if this resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks that never helped though

Comment: oh.. I have tried the same in my development env and it worked. Only difference is I have followed the steps in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content as it is.

Comment: Hey.. change 'storeFile file(/SASSI-release-key.keystore)' to 'storeFile file(SASSI-release-key.keystore)' and make sure this file is under 'android/app/' directory.

Comment: I gto a new error now
* Where:
Build file '/Users/adamkatz/Projects/Brandfoundry/react-native/sassi_old/android/app/build.gradle' line: 94

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find property 'SASSI' on SigningConfig_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=null, storePassword=null, keyAlias=null, keyPassword=null, storeType=null}.

Comment: Looks like you made some mistake while generating keystore file